# Repeat font Icon as background image

Tags: css, background-image, font-awesome

Is it possible to repeat a content as the background-image;

I saw many examples which only explains to place the font icon as a background image

Example:

```
 <ul>
      <li><li>
      <li></li>
 </ul>

  ul {
   background-image: content("\e80b");
   background-repeat:repeat-y;  
  }
```

Thanks
B L Praveen

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

**

```css
.cssClass:before{
    content: "\e84d\e84d\e84d\e84d\e84d\e84d\e84d\e84d....";
}

.cssClass {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Try use the :before selector and the content property:

```
ul:before {
  content: "\e80b"
}
```